# WPF listbox binding to listview

Tags: data-binding

I have below classes:

```
public class BusinessFunction
{
    private string str_Id;
    public string id
    {
        get { return str_Id; }
        set { str_Id = value; }
    }

    private List<Function> str_FunctionList;

    public BusinessFunction() { }

    public List<Function> functionList
    {
        get { return str_FunctionList; }
        set { str_FunctionList = value; }
    }

}

public class Function
{
    private string str_FunctionType;
    public string functionType
    {
        get { return str_FunctionType; }
        set { str_FunctionType = value; }
    }

    private string str_FunctionName;
    public string functionName
    {
        get { return str_FunctionName; }
        set { str_FunctionName = value; }
    }

    private string str_Value;
    public string value
    {
        get { return str_Value; }
        set { str_Value = value; }
    }
}
```

I have to bind the above data into Listbox and Listview. The "id" should display in listbox and the "functionList" in listview. When user changes the selection in listbox, it should bring the associated "functionList" into listview.

How to achieve this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Listview Itemsource={Binding functionList} did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Listview Itemsource={Binding functionList} did the trick.